# How to assing the value of (location.getLatitude()) to the variable "x" so I can make arithmetic operations with it

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I can display the coordinate with `(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Display)).setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));`
but I'm wondering how could I assing the value of (location.getLatitude()) to the variable "x"

```
double x;

x = ???????? valueOf(location.getLatitude())
```

Comment: double x = location.getLatitude()

Answer (score 0):

```
getLatitude() already return double type. So you do not have to convert them.
```

try this

```
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

Answer (score 0):

> getLatitude() and getLongitude() return the latitude and longitude degrees in degrees.

Firstly, you check the location.getLatitude() or location.getLongtitude() is null or not.

Example: `if(location!= null){
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
}`